# How to simplify IF statements with many conditions

Tags: javascript, typescript, conditional-statements, refactoring, nested-if

I have often come across codes samples as below.

```
if(X == x && A == a){
}
else if (X == y && A == b){
}
else if (X == z && A == c){
}
else if (X == zz && A == d){
}
```

OR sometimes conditions like this

```
if(X == x && A == a){
}
else if (X == x && A == b){
}
else if (X != x &&  A == a){
}
else if (X !=x  && A == b){
}
```

Are there more efficient and better ways to refactor this code in terms of efficiency, code clearness and Understandability?

Comment: What you mean "efficency"? This would never have any impact on the speed of the program. Always test the speed of the program in profiler. The only reason you would like to refactor this is when it don't look clean to you. If so you can write function instead of the check that would give the meaning to the condition.

Comment: Okay you are probably correct. This may be not factor to efficency directly . But isnt this make impact to the Cyclomatic complexity?

Comment: Only if you use ESLint and you're above the limit, I usually increase the limit, if I have code like this, something algorithm need to be more complex, and it's better if it's in single place, I also sometimes make small functions instead of condition if it's longer, by longer I mean when I need to break it into multiple lines because it's longer then 90 characters. in this case writing the function that have good name improve the look of the code and also make complexity smaller.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap you statement in a function, it will be a bit cleanner :

```
if(X == x && A == a){
  do_A();
}
else if (X == x && A == b){
  do_B();
}
else if (X != x &&  A == a){
  do_C()
}
else if (X !=x  && A == b){
  do_D()
}
```

would become :

```
const doSomething = () => {
  if (X == x && A == a) return do_A();
  if (X == x && A == b) return do_B();
  if (X != x &&  A == a) return do_C();
  if (X !=x  && A == b) return do_D();
};

doSomething();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use switch statement, like this: switch(expression) {
  case x:
    // code block
    break;
  case y:
    // code block
    break;
  default:
    // code block
}
however you will not have a much more efficient code as mentioned by @jcubic

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution would be to use a `switch-case` statement like so:

```
switch(X + "|" + A) {
    case x + "|" + a:
        ...
        break;
    case y + "|" + a:
        break;
    case z + "|" + c:
        break;
    case zz + "|" + d:
        break;
}
```

I don't know if you think this writing style looks better to you, but it is less efficient than the one you proposed in your question since you have to join strings before comparing them.